# What time period did these notes come from?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, currency, money

This may be a bit broad of a question, but as I was going through some old things I found some Japanese monitary bills in varying currencies from I'm guessing around WWII, but I'm not sure. I cannt read Japanese, so can anyone tell me more info. about this? Thank you!

[image: The front of the first bill (Yen)] 
[image: The back of the first bill (Yen)]

[image: The front of the second bill (Peso)]
[image: The back of the second bill (Peso)]

[image: The front of the third bill (Shilling)]
[image: The back of the third bill (Shilling)]

Comment: They're obviously fake.

Comment: @Ricky: why? (I know nothing about numismatics)

Comment: @WoJ: Me neither, but they look fake.

Comment: @WoJ Ricky is a well known troll.

Comment: @Semaphore: Thanks for the info. Also +1'ed your answer - I had no idea that there were notes which closely follow the dollar design from the "Japanese government" and labelled in pesos. The closest ones I am aware of ([Franc CFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFA_franc)) does not remotely look alike the then-Franc they were "forked" from.

Comment: @WoJ Thanks! I think these currencies usually commission brand new designs even when using the same units.

Comment: @Semaphore: the case of CFA is probably a bit special: these were initially currencies of French colonies, they retained them after liberation and till today they depend on the French National Bank (Banque de France). But as an afterthought there is indeed probably no reason for them to look like the French Franc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first set is a [Japanese 10-yen banknote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknotes_of_the_Japanese_yen#1946-48) issued in 1946, during Allied occupation of Japan.

The second set is a [one peso banknote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_government-issued_Philippine_peso) issued in 1943 in [occupied Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_occupation_of_the_Philippines) by the Japanese government.

The third set is a 1 shilling [Oceanian Pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_government-issued_Oceanian_Pound) banknote issued in 1942, also by the Japanese government, and intended for use in various occupied British and Commonwealth territories in the Pacific.